# Example of using Delta Method

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expectation, statistical-inference

Let $\hat p$ be the proportion of successes in $n$ independent Bernoulli trials each having probability $p$ of success.
(a) Compute the expectation of $\hat p (1-\hat p)$.
(b) Compute the approximate mean and variance of $\hat p (1-\hat p)$ using the Delta Method.

For part (a), I can calculate the expectation of $\hat p$ but got stuck on the expectation of $\hat p^2$, though I doubt this is a right track.

For part (b), I'm new to Delta method and as for the approximate variance I know I need to calculate the derivative of the function $\hat p (1-\hat p)$, but not quite sure. I appreciate if anyone can provide some answers or some similar examples online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$ k = #{success in n independent Bernoulli trials}$$ then we have $$ k \sim B(n,p)$$ and $$ E(\hat{p})=E(\frac{k}{n})=\frac{E(k)}{n}=\frac{np}{n}=p  $$ $$Var(\hat{p})=Var(\frac{k}{n})=\frac{Var(k)}{n^{2}}=\frac{np(1-p)}{n^{2}}=\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$$ thus $$E(\hat{p}^{2})=Var(\hat{p})+ E(\hat{p})^{2}=\frac{p-(1-n)p^{2}}{n} $$ this answers your first question.$$$$
For the second part,$$
Var(\hat{p}(1-\hat{p}))\approx(1-2\hat{p})^{2}Var(\hat{p})=(1-2\hat{p})^{2}\frac{p-(1-n)p^{2}}{n}$$ and plug in the estimate of $\hat{p}$ to get it.

Comment: thanks. How to calculate the approximate mean in part (b)?

Comment: This method is to approximate the function of the random variable in the expectation notation by using its Taylor expansion at the mean of the random variable. Here the function is $g(\hat{p})=\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$ and its mean is $p$, so the approximate mean is $E(g(\hat{p})) \approx E(g(p)+g^{'}(\hat{p})(\hat{p}-p))=g(p)+g^{'}(\hat{p})(\hat{p}-p)$. Once you use the estimate of $\hat{p}$ (which is $p$ here), the term $g^{'}(\hat{p})(\hat{p}-p)$ equals to 0, and you get the approximate mean $E(\hat{p}(1-\hat{p}))=g(p)=p(1-p)$.

Comment: Just realized that I misused $E(\hat{p}^{2})$ as $Var(\hat{p})$ in the first part. It should be $ Var(\hat{p}(1-\hat{p}))=(1-2\hat{p})^{2} \frac{p(1-p)}{n} $. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 4):

The second moment of a binomial random variable $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$ is $$E[X^2] = \operatorname{Var}(X) + E[X]^2= np(1-p) + n^2 p^2 = np(1-p+np).$$
So,
$$E[\hat{p}^2]=\frac{1}{n^2} E[X^2]=\frac{p(1-p+np)}{n}.$$

---

By the central limit theorem, you know $\sqrt{n}(\hat{p}-p) \overset{d}{\to} N(0,p(1-p))$.
You want to apply the delta method with $g(\hat{p})=\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$. The derivative of $g$ is $1-2\hat{p}$, and the square of the derivative evaluated at $p$ is $(1-2p)^2$.
Thus,
$$\sqrt{n}(\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})-p(1-p)) \overset{d}{\to} N(0,p(1-p)(1-2p)^2).$$